SQL table that will report Fld1 when criteria is met and will report Fld2 when criteria is met UNLESS Fld1 is already added to the table
All,
Imagine you have a database (File: INPUTPF) that looks as such...



Rec No
Client_Name
Class
Fld1
Fld2




1
Abbey
123
Y



2
Abbey
999
Y



3
Abbey
234
Y



4
Bill
222

N


5
Bill
333
Y
N


6
Bill
444
Y
N


7
Mike
987
Y
N


8
Mike
000
Y
N


9
Mike
999




10
Tom
666
Y
N


11
Tom
777
Y
N


12
Tom
999
Y




... and in a prior SQL statement I wrote the following code to capture ALL records where ALL of the clients if Fld1 were different:
{DROP TABLE IF EXISTS OUTPUT1;            
                            
CREATE TABLE LIB1/OUTPUT1 AS(           
    SELECT *                                   
    FROM INPUTPF                            
    WHERE Client_Name IN (                            
    SELECT Client_Name                                
    FROM INPUTPF                            
    GROUP BY Client_Name                              
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Fld1) > 1)
    )        
    WITH DATA;}

This SQL works perfect and writes out to the table OUTPUT1 ALL records for Bill (Rec No 4-6) and Mike (Rec No 7 - 9) as Fld1 for both  Bill & Mike are NOT identical. That is, Bill Fld1 is set to 'Y' for records 5 & 6 bot not record 4. Mike has Fld1 set to 'Y' for records 7 & 8 but not for record 9. The OUPPUT1 table looks as follows-



Rec No
Client_Name
Class
Fld1
Fld2




4
Bill
222

N


5
Bill
333
Y
N


6
Bill
444
Y
N


7
Mike
987
Y
N


8
Mike
000
Y
N


9
Mike
999





So Far so good!
However, now I need a new SQL that will test FLD2 for the same OUTPUT1 table but only add records if they were NOT written during the FLD1 test. So my OUTPUT1 file would look the following -



Rec No
Client_Name
Class
Fld1
Fld2




4
Bill
222

N


5
Bill
333
Y
N


6
Bill
444
Y
N


7
Mike
987
Y
N


8
Mike
000
Y
N


9
Mike
999




10
Tom
666
Y
N


11
Tom
777
Y
N


12
Tom
999
Y




Now the OUPUT1 file has Tom added as there are differences in Fld2 (Rec 10 & 11 are 'Y' but rec 12 is blank). The problem I face is with Mike. Rec No 9 for Mike differs in both Fld1 & Fld2 but I only want is written to the OUTPUT1 file one time and not twice (i.e. once for the FLD1 pass and again for the FLD2 pass). That is to say if a client's FLD1 is written to the OUTPUT1 file AND FLD2 is different DO NOT write it out again.
So my question is this-
What would be the SQL code that allow me group Client_Name and write out all of the records for Client_Name where FLD1 is NOT the same(i.e. prior code above) AND add to OUTPUT1 when Client FLD2 is different and is not added to OUTPUT1 file yet because FLD1 differences. Simply said I'm trying to avoid the addition of Mike to the table twice as he has different FLD1 AND FLD2 records.
As always thanks in advance for your time and help!

I think you need to clarify whether you do not want to write a record a second time simply because that client was written to the table with records already, or alternatively if that client AND Fld1 record hasn't been written to the table before. For instance all the Mike records could change from Y to blank and blank to Y - would you want to capture that or not? Anyway - either way in standard sql could be done with EXISTS()

You can just add OR COUNT(DISTINCT fld2) > 1 to your existing HAVING clause and get this output.

Adding to OR for fld2 worked perfect. Thanks all!

An OR is the answer
Change your line
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Fld1) > 1)

To
HAVING ( COUNT(DISTINCT Fld1) > 1 or COUNT(DISTINCT Fld2) > 1 ))

so the full select is
{DROP TABLE IF EXISTS OUTPUT1;            
                            
CREATE TABLE LIB1/OUTPUT1 AS(           
    SELECT *                                   
    FROM INPUTPF                            
    WHERE Client_Name IN (                            
    SELECT Client_Name                                
    FROM INPUTPF                            
    GROUP BY Client_Name                              
    HAVING ( COUNT(DISTINCT Fld1) > 1 or COUNT(DISTINCT Fld2) > 1 ))
    )        
    WITH DATA;}

Thanks
Oops I had not seen @JNevill comment above which is the same. I might delete this answer.

Leave it as an answer. @JNevill should have written an answer anyway.
